# what are measurable spaces on the real line?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I've  came across this [article](http://planetmath.org/dominatedconvergencetheorem) about the dominated convergence theorem , but since i didn't take a course on measure theory , i have some problems understanding the language of the previously or [other](http://planetmath.org/criterionforinterchangingsummationandintegration) stated theorems .
I specifically have two questions :

- What are measurable spaces on the real line ? is every interval a measurable space ?
- When we talk about a measurable function in the real line , we mean by that an integrable function ?

Comment: 1, Yes it can be but i dont think you know what you on about and 2, no, measurable is much weaker than integrable. i think you need to consult a book. These are basic definitions, but it is hard to explain to someone who do not know the basics like what is a measure space.

Comment: @Lost1 Ok , but every time i look for statements about interchanging limits like DCT , i'm faced with this problem (I need these tools in the context of real analysis not the measure theory)

Comment: If the absolute value of a sequence of functions is dominated by an integrable function, then limit of integral equals to the integral of the pointwise limit of the function. That is dct. Forget measurability. Nice functions like semi continuous functions are always measurable.

Comment: @Lost1 and this is true even if we are talking about intervals like [0 , + $\infty$[ or ]- $\infty$ , + $\infty$[ ?

Comment: Yes, always okay in Rn.

Comment: @Lost1 Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of summary. This is not rigorous but probably applicable for the OP's situation.

If you are dealing with nice functions in $R^n$, if the absolutely value of a sequence of functions is bounded by an integrable function, then the limit of the integral is the same as integral of the point wise limit of the functions.